# How to print an item in a label (.settext) from a list using Scenebuilder/Intellij

Tags: java, list, button, intellij-idea, scenebuilder

Having problems creating a list within the main and controller classes that can be cycled through using a button.

My idea is to have an actionevent from a button print an item from a list within a label on the gui, with each click of the button adding 1 to the index of the list, thus cycling through and displaying the strings.

Not sure where exactly to put the list, so that it can be accessed after a button is pressed. Code is written in Java using Intellij IDE and SceneBuilder

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, as person who mostly deals with c#, I was still in the mindset of using 'elementAt' commands to fetch data from lists, rather than the get command.